# Sed command garbled with very easy mutiline regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I'm again garbled with sed command, because most probably i have very old version of sed but according to my limitations i couldn't change the version of 'sed' (!)

My question is this i wrote such an easy regex that fits with my string file such as:

```
/[^,]*$/mg
```

My string file is this :

```
23:53:20,650
23:53:20,654
23:53:20,655
23:53:20,656
23:53:21,238
23:53:21,240
23:53:21,302
23:53:21,303
23:53:21,304
23:53:21,305
23:53:21,889
23:53:21,890
23:53:21,896
23:53:21,897
23:53:21,898
23:53:21,899
23:53:22,492
23:53:22,538
23:53:22,539
23:53:23,109
23:53:23,110
23:53:23,115
23:53:23,117
23:53:23,118
23:53:23,119
23:53:23,690
23:53:23,721
23:53:23,722
23:53:24,275
23:53:24,276
23:53:24,313
23:53:24,316
23:53:24,317
23:53:24,318
23:53:24,854
23:53:24,888
23:53:24,889
23:53:24,890
23:53:24,891
23:53:50,676
23:53:50,677
23:53:50,711
23:53:50,713
23:53:50,714
23:53:51,257
23:53:51,258
23:53:51,296
23:53:51,297
23:53:51,298
23:53:51,820
23:53:51,822
23:53:51,823
23:53:52,358
23:53:52,364
23:53:52,367
23:53:52,909
23:53:52,910
23:53:52,936
23:53:52,939
23:53:52,941
23:53:52,944
23:53:52,945
23:53:52,946
23:53:52,949
23:53:52,953
23:53:52,956
23:53:52,959
23:53:52,963
23:53:52,966
23:53:52,970
23:53:52,971
23:53:52,974
23:53:52,978
23:53:52,980
23:53:52,983
23:53:52,984
23:53:52,986
23:53:52,987
23:53:52,989
23:53:52,990
23:53:52,991
23:53:52,994
23:53:52,995
23:53:52,999
23:53:53,001
23:53:53,002
23:53:53,004
23:53:53,005
23:53:53,007
23:53:53,010
23:53:53,026
23:53:53,027
23:53:53,081
23:53:53,082
23:53:53,083
23:53:53,085
07:32:54,519
07:32:54,521
07:32:54,537
07:32:54,538
07:32:54,539
07:32:54,540
07:32:54,541
07:32:54,542
07:32:54,543
07:32:54,544
07:32:54,545
07:32:54,546
07:32:54,547
07:32:54,548
07:32:54,549
07:32:54,550
```

I'm trying to get the values after the comma then assign them into array, when I used the sed command like :

```
`sed -n '/[^,]*$/mg'` file
```

It says command garbled, i read about multiline sed but i still couldn't reach to solution, i am new to regexes so the help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you just use `cut -d\, -f2 file`?  or is the output from that sed expected to be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a "recent" bash, I think you can use cut and assign extracted values to an array:

```
numbers="$(cut -d',' -f2 filename.txt)"
array_numbers=( $numbers )
```

Comment: as an addition, Could you please tell me the that how command works ?

Comment: The `cut` command is using the comma to as token 'd'elimiter and taking the second 'f'ield. This will be done on each row in the given filename. 
The result will be a single multiline string called `numbers` containing all the numbers needed. 
The array of numbers called `array_numbers` is done by using the shell expansion: in this row we are taking the values inside the multiline string and representing as a single line string (note: we don't use quotes) with numbers speared by a space. So the result is something like: `array_numbers=( 896 897 ... )` that is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the values after comma then you could use the below sed command which removes the values from the start upto the first comma.

```
sed 's/^[^,]*,//' file
```

OR

```
sed 's/^.*,//' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo '23:53:22,492' | sed 's/^[^,]*,//'
492
$ echo '23:53:22,492' | sed 's/^.*,//'
492
```

Comment: `^.*,` will do the same.

Comment: even shorter `sed 's/.*,//'`

Comment: Thank you for your help but why /mg part of my regex is garbled ? Do you have an idea about it ?

Answer (score 0):

`sed s/.*,// file`
would match the till the first `,` are substitute the match wth nothing, which effectively gives the values after comma

for the input file

```
23:53:20,650
23:53:20,654
23:53:20,655
23:53:20,656
23:53:21,238
23:53:21,240
23:53:21,302
23:53:21,303
23:53:21,304
23:53:21,305
23:53:21,889
23:53:21,890
23:53:21,896
23:53:21,897
23:53:21,898
23:53:21,899
23:53:22,492
23:53:22,538
```

will produce output as

```
650
654
655
656
238
240
302
303
304
305
889
890
896
897
898
899
492
538
```

Comment: sed s/.*,// file would match until the **last** ,